# Is there a fonction to overlay a data form a Higher Time Frame ? (PineScript)

Tags: pine-script

I am currently scripting an indicator for my strategy, and I want to overlay the Bollinger Bands from a higher time frame on my chart. 
I want it to be dynamic. So if example I am on the 15 minutes chart, I want to have the possibility to plot the Bollinger Bands from the 30 minutes chart.

I know I have to use the security fonction but don't really understand why it is not working.

I am beginner in pine script coding so please be indulgent.

Please help me

```
study(shorttitle="Framework", title="Framework BB + TD9", 
overlay=true)

//-------------//
//---Context---//
//-------------//


src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)

length = input(20, minval=1, defval=20)

mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)

dev = mult * stdev(src, length)

ema1 = ema(src, length)

ema2 = ema(ema1, length)

ema3 = ema(ema2, length)

out = 3 * (ema1 - ema2) + ema3

src_H4 = security(tickerid, '240', src)

ema1_H4 = ema(src_H4, 20)

ema2_H4 = ema(ema1_H4, 20)

ema3_H4 = ema(ema2_H4, 20)

out_H4 = 3 * (ema1_H4 - ema2_H4) + ema3_H4


CTup= out_H4 + (0.764*dev)

CTUP= out_H4 + (1*dev)

CTdn= out_H4 - (0.764*dev)

CTDN= out_H4 - (1*dev)


p5 = plot(CTup, color=gray, linewidth=1, transp=100, 
title="0.764")

p6 = plot(CTUP, color=red, linewidth=2, transp=100, title="1")

p17 = plot(CTdn, color=gray, linewidth=1, transp=100, 
title="0.764")

p18 = plot(CTDN, color=blue, linewidth=2, transp=100, title="1")




fill(p5, p6, color=#383435, transp=77, title="Sell Context")

fill(p17, p18, color=#383435, transp=77, title="Buy Context")
```

The code is actually for the 4H chart but it was just for testing. I was expecting to have a very big channel if example I was going in 1 minute chart with a 4H bollinger bands, but it is the same size. I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all calcs down to `security()`. Have a look at how the `f_hiBB()` and `f_loBB()` functions are passed to `security()` calls in the [Visual RSI indicator](https://www.tradingview.com/script/XcGCX8DG-Visual-RSI-LucF/). The functions do not return conventional BBs but they could be adapted. The way they are used illustrates one way you could go about resolving your challenge.